# Starting the spawned server on port XXXX ... ERROR: Spawn server operation failed

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, frm

I am using MySQL Utilities to recover a table schema from .frm file. Every time I run mysqlfrm command in default mode, I get this message:

Starting the spawned server on port XXXX ... ERROR: Spawn server operation failed. To diagnose, run the utility again and use the --verbose option to view the messages from the spawned server and correct any errors presented then run the utility again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaFib.png)

So I run the same command using -verbose. This time the message is:

```
Starting the spawned server on port 5974 ... ERROR: Port 5974 in use. Please choose an available port.
```

If I change the port and run command using -verbose:

```
Starting the spawned server on port XXXX ... ERROR: Spawn server operation failed. To diagnose, run the utility again and use the --verbose option to view the messages from the spawned server and correct any errors presented then run the utility again.
```

Running command in --diagnostic mode I get:

```
Reading .frm file for wp_commentmeta.frm:
# The .frm file is a TABLE.
```

ERROR: Cannot read column header.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYqf0.png)

Any idea?